# Linux System Call: Custom Control Messages

Tags: linux

Does anyone know which system call I would use in order to send custom control messages to certain devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the ioctl system call - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html

If you were writing your own device driver you'd use ioctl to send device-specific control instructions.